# Android Studio Error 55, 0

Tags: android

I try to add Firebase Cloud Messages for my app but I get an error when I try to sync it.

[image: Error]

I'm not sure version of what its about and how can I solve it.
Thanks.

Here is the build.gradle file of app module:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    packagingOptions {

        exclude('META-INF/NOTICE')
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude('META-INF/LICENSE')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.com.qascript.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName '1.7'
        versionCode 11
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please post your gradle file content.

Comment: Post your grade file of your app module

Comment: have your added 

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

in your project gradle

Comment: Added after an edit in question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the [Google Play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) of your device to minimum version 9.0. Unless you device Google Play services version is less then 9.0 you won't be able to use firebase services in your device.

Comment: This error appear on Android Studio not on a device.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line in your gradle file. You are using older version of play services and also update your SDK from Sdk manager and try to get newer version of play service and support versions.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.4'
```

Comment: now, I get this: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

Comment: Please update your SDK and update your compile sdk version and build tools also...This is mandatory

Comment: Error:(51, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.4
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:/Users/avidican/Downloads/AskAndAnswerApp/Android Project (client)/QA Script/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Please see my reply.